# vue-route pass different props to different view component when router changed in vuejs2.0?

Tags: vue.js, vuejs2, vue-router

In [this ticket](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/37937262/passing-props-to-vue-js-components-instantiated-by-vue-router), we can pass parameters to component when the route changes via

```
<router-view class="view" :propForA="AData"></router-view>
```

My question is If we need pass different props to different routed component,
say, for example, propForB property will have `BData` ,  `propForC` property will have `CData`

how to achieve that? Especially in vuejs2.0?

Answer (score 1):

I would send one prop with different values that fits your component... For example:

```
<router-view class="view" :propData="propToSend"></router-view>
```

then something like this

```
export default {

  data: function () {
    return {
      propAData: {
        something: 'value',
        somethingElese: ['other', 'value']
      },
      propBData: {
        somethingOther: 123
      },
      propToSend: null
    }
  },

  watch: {
    '$route': function (val, oldVal) {
      if (this.$route.name === 'Something') {
        this.propToSend = this.propAData
      } else {
        this.propToSend = this.propBData
      }
    }
  }
}
```

There are of-course other ways, to achieve same result...

Comment: this solution works to some extend, but does not fit exactly what i want. This add a wrapper to property, i must change every component's defination object to retrieve props via propAData.something and propAData.somethingElse. I like it to introduce no change for the tons of legacy components. Just now, i workaround it to give all the props data in the router-view defination, this looks ugly, but it works.