# Send data to components in VueJS + Vue Router

Tags: laravel, vue-component, vuejs2, vue.js, vue-router

I can't pass data from app to compenent. After render it shows only clear html, without data from vue. All works, but without data((

My code from app.js:

```
var Series = Vue.component('Series', require('./components/Series.vue'),{
    props: {
        series: {
            type: Array,
            default: []
        },
        images: {
            type: Array,
            default: []
        },
        showPhotos: {
            type: Boolean,
            default: false
        }
    }
});
const Bar = { template: '<div>bar</div>' }
const Foo = { template: '<div>foo</div>' }

const routes = [
  { path: '/weedings', component: Series },
  { path: '/', component: Foo },
  { path: '/family', component: Foo },
  { path: '/other', component: Foo },
  { path: '/videos', component: Bar },
  { path: '/blog', component: Bar },
  { path: '/about', component: Foo },
  { path: '/contacts', component: Bar }
]
const router = new VueRouter({
  routes // short for routes: routes
});
var app = new Vue({
    el: "#app",
    router,
    data: {
        series: [],
        currentSerie: 0,
        images: [],
        showPhotos: false
    },
    methods: {
        fetchSeries: function(){
            this.$http.get('/api/fetchSeries').then((response) => {
                this.series = response.body
            }, (response) => {
                alert("fail")
            });
        },
        fetchPhotos: function(id){
            this.showPhotos = false;
            this.$http.get('/api/fetchPhotos/'+id).then((response) => {
                this.images = response.body
                this.showPhotos = true;
                $("html, body").animate({ scrollTop: 60 }, "500");
            }, (response) => { 
                alert("fail")
            });
        },
        photos: function(id){
            this.fetchPhotos(id)
        }
    },
    created: function(){
        this.fetchSeries()
        setTimeout(function(){ require('./custom'); }, 1000);
    }

});
```

When I dont use vue-router, all works fine. And i know i can pass data to components in this way: `<my-component :artribute="value"></my-component>`, but in this case IDK how to pass data.

Comment: Are you using any preprocessor? What is the second parameter in the `Vue.component()`, I've never seen a signature with three parameters for component registration, but I may be wrong.

Comment: I use webpack (Laravel Elixir).
Look here default app.js from laravel https://github.com/laravel/laravel/blob/master/resources/assets/js/app.js

Comment: In your link, the `Vue.component()` call has two parameters which is correct, here your code has three.

Comment: And you shouldn't be calling the `Vue.component` multiple times for same component registration(`Series` is registered once at the top, then re-registered in routes definition).

Comment: @MathewJibin, my bad, forgot to edit this. 
`var Series = Vue.component('Series', require('./components/Series.vue'),{
 props: {
  series: {
   type: Array,
      default: []
  },
  images: {
   type: Array,
      default: []
  },
  showPhotos: {
   type: Boolean,
      default: false
  }
 }
});

const routes = [
  { path: '/weedings', component: Series },
]`

Comment: Please dont share code in comments, you'll further get comments asking for same code. Edit it into question.

Comment: Your third argument to `Vue.component()` call doesn't make any sense. It accepts only two parameters and second one being the options argument, is being imported from the file `./components/Series.vue`, your third argument is probably being ignored. Are you sure the options defined in that file has all properties defined correctly?

Answer (score 3):

Use function mode like this:

```
{
    path: '/weedings',
    component: Series,
    props: () => (
        { series: app.series, images: app.images, showPhotos: app.showPhotos }
    )
}
```

Check working example in [JSFiddle](http://jsfiddle.net/aqkvmqzs/).

**Note:** You have to use [vuex](https://vuex.vuejs.org/) as a centralized store for all the components in an application to be able to implement more complex scenarios.

Answer (score 0):

In your routes declaration you should add props

```
`const routes = [
    { path: '/weedings', component: Series, props: true}]`
```

Here mentioned: [Passing props to Vue.js components instantiated by Vue-router](https://stackoverflow.com/a/43315473/6672310)

Comment: From the docs: When props is set to true, the route.params will be set as the component props.